# How do I reorder tableview rows using fetchedresultscontroller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm, trying to reorder the cells in a table view using core data and nsfetchresultscontroller. I found a few ways of doing this using objective C (of which I know nothing) and tried implementing them in swift, here's what I came up with:

```
var books: Array<AnyObject> = []

// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    books = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!

    let book = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(fromIndexPath)

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil

    books.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
    books.insert(book, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)

    var i = 0
    for book in books {
        book.setValue(i++, forKey: "position")
    }

    try! context.save()

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

}
```

The delegate and context references are in an extension in another file.
With this code sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I change the order, run the app again and it's in a completely different order that I can't figure out. Especially when I move more than one row at once. And if I print each object's "position" atribute to the console I can see they're really not being updated properly. But why not?

What am I doing wrong? What would be a better option?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

---

Edit:

**Ok, here's the working code:**

```
func initializeFetchedResultsController() {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Book")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "position", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
        try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
    }
}

// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    initializeFetchedResultsController()
    var objects = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects! as! [ObjectClass]

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil

    let object = objects[fromIndexPath.row]
    objects.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
    objects.insert(object, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)

    var i = 0
    for object in objects {
        object.position = i++
    }

    try! context.save()

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
}
```

The trick is that the initializeFetchedResultsController function, besides being at viewDidLoad, where I had it, must be repeated inside the moveRowAtIndexPath bit. Also, the initializing function and the array declaration must both be before setting the FRC delegate to nil (obviously, but it's easy to miss).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't edit `books`, it doesn't belong to you and is effectively private data. Instead you should just be updating the objects that are moving to change the `position` value. If you do this using array reordering as in your current logic you should create a new mutable copy of the array provided by the FRC. You should also be setting the new values for the position as `NSNumber` instances.

Comment: Uhm, I thought it already was a mutable copy. How do I do that, then? Sorry for the stupid questions, this is my first try at programming at all.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear from the docs, in obj-c it's immutable, in swift it could well be a copy you can edit. Probably the `NSNumber` part is the issue.

Comment: Well, for that should I just use "i as NSNumber"? I tried that, xcode doesn't complain, but it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: I'm thinking about how to do it updating the objects that are moving, like you said. The thing is that when I delete and object I'll have to decrease the position of every object that comes after it by one, and I don't know how to do that without an array...

Comment: The array should be fine, debug to check what numbers are being updated into the managed objects during the loop

Comment: I added the updated code to the end of my question. Now the positions are being updated correctly (012, 012 etc.), but not for the right objects. It's like they're in a different order in the array every time. The array get's updated with the right positions, but it doesn't match the order I see at my table view.

Comment: Phew! Ok, I got it. I thought I didn't have to repeat the sort descriptor inside the moverowatindexpath function, but apparently I did have to. I repeated the initializing function before defining the array and now it all works out. I'll accept your answer as the most helpful and add the working code to my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a sortDescriptor, then the information you get back from the fetch request is already sorted. This is how I implement my fetchRequests:

```
lazy var connectionsFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = {
   var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Connection")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: ["user", UserManager.SharedInstance.user!])
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true)]
    request.predicate = predicate
    return request
}()
```

Comment: I am doing that… I'll update the question with the code.

Comment: Please show more code. We need to know what you're already doing. Please you post your fetchRequest.